# Port already in use exception with java RMI using CMD

Tags: java, exception, cmd, rmi

while Running RMI using java and CMD. java.rmi.server.ExportException is displayed. The Exception is that, port is already in use.

[image: I organised the Client and Server programs this way]

The server interface

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface AdditionInterface extends Remote {
    public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
}
```

The Interface implementation

```
import java.rmi.Naming; 
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class AdditionClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String host="";
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            AdditionInterface hello = (AdditionInterface) registry.lookup("Addition");
            int result = hello.add(9, 2);
            System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("HelloClient Exception" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The Server Registry class

```
package chapter40;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class AdditionServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            AdditionInterface obj = new Addition();
            registry.rebind("Addition", obj);

            System.out.println("Addition Server is ready");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Addition Server failed" + ex);
        }

    }

}
```

The client program

```
import java.rmi.Naming; 
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class AdditionClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String host="";
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            AdditionInterface hello = (AdditionInterface) registry.lookup("Addition");
            int result = hello.add(9, 2);
            System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("HelloClient Exception" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I separated the server from the client classes in two different projects for clarity sake

Comment: You probably already have an instance of your program running that you forgot to stop.

Comment: You might have a previous instance still running.

Comment: There is nothing here that would cause this error. What did? Maybe the constructor of `Addition`, but you haven't shown it.

Answer (score -1):

I searched through various threads and finally got this to work in a way different from [ but also a combination from what I'd seen ]

RUN THE SERVER PROGRAM THUS (from the command prompt):

1. change the directory to the source folder for the server
   `cd c:\Users\Heavenly\workspace\RMIServerSide\src`
2. compile the classes
   `javac chapter40/*.java`
3. start the RMI registry
   `start rmiregistry`
4. start the registry server class  containing the main() method. NOTE THE LINE OF CODE IS SLIGHTLY DIFFERENT

`start  java  -cp  .  chapter40.AdditionServer`  
(the server is now set)

RUN THE CLIENT PROGRAM

1. Change the directory to the source folder
   `cd c:\Users\Heavenly\workspace\RMIClientSide\src`
2. compile all the classes
   `javac chapter40/*.java`

3.Run the client program
`java chapter40.AdditionClient`  
(everything is running now)

Comment: Nothing here that would solve the problem stated. Note the line of code [by which you mean the command line] is slightly different from what?

Comment: I had the problem, and this procedure solved it. I don't know what else you are saying